# Re-Downloading an app after switching Apple ID country: Does the old app data stay (stored files, level progress in games, ...)?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

I need to change the country of my Apple ID, and I already found that fortunately any apps that did cost money will be available for free download after I do this (as long as the app exists in my new country of course).

But I couldn't find out whether **the data of the app is also kept** when I redownload an app I already have on my device - like the progress in a game, any data that is stored like photos or documents etc.

Does anyone happen to know?

Comment: I am not sure if one can per se answer this. Are we talking about iOS or macOS? It may also depend on where the game is saved to and if it is connected to iCloud or to some app account. I'd argue most apps would be able to access the old data again, but it may depend. However, make sure to have a backup!

Comment: iOS primarily, but also macOs for some apps. I'm most concerned about apps that do not store data in the cloud, only local storage. The base question here is whether this download is just installing over the existing app like a new version, or if it is replacing the app as if it would be a new app

Comment: If you offload the app, then redownload it, it will retain its data. This is how I accomplish when I need to redownload from a new account. I can't guarantee this will work when switching regions.

Comment: I dont think re-installing an app stores data anyway, only if you offload as @EzekielElin said. Also many games will sync with game center or iCloud for progress. Make sure to backup to mac or iCloud though!

Answer (score 1):

Changing which country's App Store you're logged in to does not require you to re-download your apps. All installed apps will continue to work as before. You do not need to delete the app and re-download it from the new country.

In case you have apps that were installed, but currently not stored on the device due to offloading, you can re-download those apps even after changing country - and your data will still be there.

Note: Some apps are not offered in all countries. In those cases, you might find that if you delete an app, and try to re-download it, it is simply not available for purchase (or free download) within your new country.